# SQL-Stored proc update with multiple filter conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using ms sql server. I am trying to create SP for the below scenario.
I've to update the sourceDB from Temp mapping table(overwritten) everyday with different conditions, I am getting error with my below code.So please some one suggest how to get this done.

```
/**Here is my code:**/

Create Proc SP_Source_DBMapping

AS

Create table Table_Mapping

(
[User] varchar(50),
[Call_Date] datetime,
[Final_status] varchar (255),
[Category] varchar (255),
[V_Date] datetime,
[V_Time] time,
[Comments] varchar(max),
[CB_Date] datetime,
[key] varchar(255) Primary key
)
bulk insert Table_Mapping
from 'D:\DB\Source.Csv'
with
(
firstrow =2,
fieldterminator =',',
rowterminator = '\n'
)

IF SourceTable.[Callable Status] <> 'Closed'
    or
    SourceTable.Final_Status not like 'call done%' and 
    SourceTable.[Callable Status] = 'Closed' and
    [dbo].[Table_Mapping].Final_Status like 'call done%'

Begin
update ST set [User] = TM.[User]
,[Call_Date] = TM.[Call_Date]
,Final_Status = TM.Final_Status
,[Category]=TM.[Category]
,[V_Date]=TM.[V_Date]
,[V_Time]=TM.[V_Time]
,[Comments]=TM.[Comments]
,[CB_Date]=TM.[CB_Date]
,[Attempt Date I]=
case when [Attempt Date I] = null Then TM.[Call_Date]
End
,[Attempt Date II]=
case when [Attempt Date I] <> TM.[Call_Date] and [Attempt Date II] = null Then TM.[Call_Date]
 end
,[Attempt Date III]=
case when [Attempt Date I] <> TM.[Call_Date] and [Attempt Date II] <> TM.[Call_Date] and [Attempt Date III] = null Then TM.[Call_Date]
 end

From DB1.SourceTable as ST
inner join Table_Mapping as TM
on ST.[Key]=TM.[Key]
--where exists (select [key] from DB1.SourceTable)
Drop Table Table_Mapping
End
```

Comment: show what error you are getting?

Comment: Temp tables are created with # prefix .  Use #Table_Mapping instead of Table_Mapping

Comment: It seems the conditions from `IF` statement (which doesn't work and should issue a syntax error) have to be moved to the where clause of your UPDATE statement.

Comment: @ Shikhar Arora--> Thanks for the Prefix thing it works fine now.

Comment: @Denis Rubashkin --> Thanks for the advice to change the condition in where clause it works fine now.